# Explain why these two multi-dimensional arrays seem like valid syntax yet only one gives expected results?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've just realised the error of my ways in a bit of code that fills up a c 2 dimensional array.

I declared the array like this:

```
int myArray[5][5];
```

..but mistakenly set a value with:

```
*myArray[3,4] = 10;
```

..when it should have been:

```
myArray[3][4] = 10;
```

Ok, the first line is a mistake but it compiled and ran, albeit with very strange results. (ie, when I tried to print out the contents of *myArray[3,4], it had the wrong value in)

**Can someone explain what exactly that first assignment statement is *doing*?**

edit: I originally tried to use:

```
myArray[3,4] = 10;
```

..which threw a compiler error about me trying to assign an int to a *int type. I guess it evaluated 3,4 to 4 as per the answer below and figured that I was trying to add 4 to a pointer so should be using pointer addressing to access the array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Comma has value of the second espression: (a,b) is b: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator

`*myArray[3,4]` is like `*myArray[4]`

Comment: This has the effect of assigning to `myArray[4][0]`.

Comment: Nope it has the effect of assigning *myArray[4] address 10, see my reply below.

Comment: Ach yes indeed, my bad! Should look more carefully before posting. Will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

*myArray[3,4] = 10;

This is accidently using an obscure feature of the C language called "the comma operator", which evaluates the expression left-to-right. Without going into the details about that, it skips the 3 and takes the 4. This is what the compiler sees:

*myArray[4] = 10;

You really should have gotten a compiler warning from this, if you have a decent compiler.

Comment: No, `*myArray[4]` is equivalent to `myArray[4][0]` and is an `int`